C++ error handling in assembly level, why it can know jumping to the correct line of asm code?
In this sample:
https://godbolt.org/z/bx8oeWrxd
square(int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     edi, 8
        call    __cxa_allocate_exception
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax], OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     edx, 0
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:typeinfo for char const*
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    __cxa_throw
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 24
        mov     edi, 4
        call    square(int)
.L6:
        mov     eax, 0
        jmp     .L10
        cmp     rdx, 1
        je      .L5
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    _Unwind_Resume

Why it will know directly jumping to .L6 after thrown the exception

cmp rdx, 1

not starting from .L6

mov eax, 0

because if it continues executing the code after called square(int),
it will enter .L6 and jmp .L10, the remaining code will never be ran.
Therefore, it may directly jump to the code cmp rdx, 1 after executed call __cxa_throw. But why it can know it have to jump to the line of cmp rdx, 1?

questions should be self-contained and not rely on external links

"Why it will know directly jumping" isn't proper English. I don't understand what you're asking.

Note that if (4) is the same as if (true).

The answer is "because the exception table defines it that way". If you turn off the directives filter you can search for "gcc_except_table". I don't know how to interpret that table but it might give you a clue what to look for.
